# Drupal permission required for CiviCRM home page?

Tags: drupal, permissions

What is the minimum required Drupal permission to access drupalroot/civicrm?reset=1?

I'm trying to set up a role for users who need access to the contacts database but shouldn't have any admin rights. I've ticked all the permissions for things like add/view/edit contacts, and unticked anything that sounds like access to the backend. Whenever I go to the CiviCRM homepage as a user with that role I just see a message that says 'Access denied You are not authorised to access this page.' If I go directly to the URL of a specific contact I can view and edit it, but I can't see an interface to browse or search them by.

Answer (score 3):

The user should have **CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API** permission

Comment: The description 'master control' and 'give to trusted roles only' on that permission sound like something that should be for admin roles only. Is that not the case? What are the concerns that it might raise?

Comment: I had the exact same concerns.  And, having granted this, I still find that my user is unable to access events, mailings and campaigns, although those menu options are at least now visible.  I really wish someone in the know might provide a comprehensive set of documentation, perhaps even embedded as modal popups on the permission pages.  I'd appreciate a menu option by menu option guide to granting access to CiviCRM.